# Removing the first row in DataGridView actually removes all rows

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating an application in C#, Windows Forms.

I have a `DataGridView` and in it I have a column which contains `Button`s (`DataGridView` `Button` columns). I created an On `Button` click event and so it calls a method which removes a row:

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
        {
            if (!dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
            {
                dataGridView.Rows.Remove(dataGridView.CurrentRow); // removes current row
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I'm first adding rows and then I remove them if I need, if I remove the last row there is no problem.
The problem occurs if I try to remove the first or any other row except the last. If - for example - I remove the first row, all rows are deleted. When I debugged it, it seems that the method repeats itself as many times there are rows are in my `DataGrid`.

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have some other code which selects/sets the current selected row in the `DataGridView`.

Might be a chance that there is some other code, which is actually sending the space key to the currently selected row, so when a row is deleted, `CellClick` event also gets fired on the next row. Just a guess BTW.

Also, try to use the `CellContentClick` or `CellMouseClick` events.

Comment: CellContentClick did the trick and save me a lot of time. Thank you very much. Can I buy you a beer? ;)

Comment: heyyy... it's a great catch up. You are a hero! :-)

Answer (score 0):

change: `dataGridView.Rows.Remove(dataGridView.CurrentRow);` 
to: `dataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);`

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help me :/

Comment: @Thorusan86, you may need to provide more code then, as from your code above there is no way for us to reproduce the problem you are facing. My guess is that there must be something like a "For loop" in your code has caused this problem.